# Handling Click events within ListView

Tags: android, listview, click, onitemclicklistener

I have created a customized `ListView`. The `ListView` contains some information about each object, and 2 buttons, for Edit and Delete. I have attached it with an `ArrayList` object through customized `ListViewAdapter` for the information.

Now, I want the buttons to update the `ArrayList` object when they are clicked. I cannot find a way to do it. I followed the instruction found in this link..

http://www.migapro.com/click-events-listview-gridview/

The program does not throw any error. But it does not do anything as well. For now, I just wanted to test by throwing a toast for each button click.

The code for the `ListViewAdapter.getView()` method is :

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;

    // check if the view already exists
    // if so, no need to inflate and findViewById again!
    if (convertView == null) {

        // Inflate the custom row layout from your XML.
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);

        // create a new "Holder" with subviews
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.itemNameView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_name);
        holder.itemExpiryView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_expiry);

        // Taking care of the buttons
        holder.editButton = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button_edit);
        holder.editButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ((ListView) parent).performItemClick(v, position, 0); // Let the event be handled in onItemClick()
            }
        });

        holder.deleteButton = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button_delete);
        holder.deleteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ((ListView) parent).performItemClick(v, position, 0); // Let the event be handled in onItemClick()
            }
        });



        // hang onto this holder for future recycling
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {

        // skip all the expensive inflation/findViewById
        // and just get the holder you already made
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    // More code after this

    // Grab the title and author from the JSON
    String name = "";
    String expiry = "7 days";

    // Write appropriate codes to obtain values for the string variables above
    name = (String) getItem(position);

    // Send these Strings to the TextViews for display
    holder.itemNameView.setText(name);
    holder.itemExpiryView.setText(expiry);

    return convertView;
}
```

I have implemented the OnItemClickListener() in MainActivity and wrote this code-snippet to handle button clicks.

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    long viewId = view.getId();

    if (viewId == R.id.button_edit) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Edit Button CLicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else if (viewId == R.id.button_delete) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Delete Button CLicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "ListView clicked" + id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

The corresponding layout file looks like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/item_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/item_expiry"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/item_name" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_edit"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/item_expiry"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:text="Edit"
    android:clickable="true" />
    <!--android:onClick="editItem" />-->

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_delete"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/item_expiry"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:text="Delete"
    android:clickable="true" />
    <!--android:onClick="ItemEdits.deleteItem" />-->


</RelativeLayout>
```

If you guys need more code-snippets, please let me know. Could not find anything on logcat. So, can't help with any error code/warning message. Thanks a lot in advance.

What I am trying to achieve here is that, when I click on the Edit/Delete button, I need to call a function to modify the ArrayList storing the list values. And somehow, I need to pass the position of the item clicked so that I can update the correct information. Is there a better way to do it? If so, then please help me out with a code sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You add click action inside of if(convertview == null). which is needs to change try the following. It is just one issue. try this and let me know what could be the result.

```
@Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;

        // check if the view already exists
        // if so, no need to inflate and findViewById again!
        if (convertView == null) {

            // Inflate the custom row layout from your XML.
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);

            // create a new "Holder" with subviews
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.itemNameView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_name);
            holder.itemExpiryView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_expiry);

            // Taking care of the buttons
            holder.editButton = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button_edit);
            holder.deleteButton = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button_delete);


            // hang onto this holder for future recycling
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {

            // skip all the expensive inflation/findViewById
            // and just get the holder you already made
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.editButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ((ListView) parent).performItemClick(v, position, 0); // Let the event be handled in onItemClick()
            }
        });

        holder.deleteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ((ListView) parent).performItemClick(v, position, 0); // Let the event be handled in onItemClick()
            }
        });

        // More code after this

        // Grab the title and author from the JSON
        String name = "";
        String expiry = "7 days";

        // Write appropriate codes to obtain values for the string variables above
        name = (String) getItem(position);

        // Send these Strings to the TextViews for display
        holder.itemNameView.setText(name);
        holder.itemExpiryView.setText(expiry);

        return convertView;
    }
```

**Note :** use onclick inside of getView method or use onItemClick method. Using both will create some issues.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Changed accordingly. And yes, keeping both OnClick and OnItemClick raises problems. I would try to define functions for edit and delete inside the OnClick methods only rather than passing it to new OnItemClick function.. :) Thanks for pointing out. I may update this very thread asking for more help. Nice meeting you.